# Script that when an prefab is in an folder called mods, a button appears in the scene and when clicked it spawns the prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I wanted to make a simple mod support script but it got tedious very fast. The goal is that people can make prefabs and the put them into the game to give that mod idea. To specify my problem I want to make a script that (on the exported Windows version) checks if there is a mods folder in the resources folder if that exists it will check for prefabs in the mods folder if there are it will make a ui button pop up in the scene with the name of the prefab then when you click it, it spawns the prefab at 0,0,0.

For anyone wanting a picture with how that would have looked [here is the game](https://tjeesse.itch.io/boxsand) it would have been a sort of spawn menu with mods showing up as the buttons like the pictures of the game.

So I made the script below but it just never worked, like it did find the mod folder but it does not want to spawn the prefab with a button, but other times it did not find the mods folder in the resources folder. I don't know what to do any more.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;

public class ModLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject buttonPrefab;
    public VerticalLayoutGroup verticalLayout;
    private string modFolder = "Mods";
    private string modPath;

    private void Start()
    {
        modPath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Resources", modFolder);
        if(Directory.Exists(modPath)){
            // Get all prefabs in the mod folder
            Object[] prefabs = Resources.LoadAll(modFolder, typeof(GameObject));
            for (int i = 0; i < prefabs.Length; i++)
            {
                GameObject prefab = (GameObject)prefabs[i];
                // Create a button for each prefab
                GameObject button = Instantiate(buttonPrefab, verticalLayout.transform);
                button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = prefab.name;
                int index = i;
                button.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => SpawnPrefab(index));
            }
        }else{
            Debug.Log("Mod folder not found");
        }
    }

    private void SpawnPrefab(int index)
    {
        // Instantiate the prefab at position (0,0,0)
        Object[] prefabs = Resources.LoadAll(modFolder, typeof(GameObject));
        GameObject prefab = (GameObject)prefabs[index];
        Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Assets and Objects in the Resources folders are serialized when the project is built.  [Assets, Resources, and Asset Bundles](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7)

Comment: @hijinxbassist Well i want to make that when the project is build you then later put the prefabs in the resources > mods folder so that people can like ‘mod’ the game

Comment: I understand.  Unfortunately, assets and objects that are contained in the resources folder are serialized when you build the project.  This is how the Resources API works.  It does not use the file system in the way you describe.

Comment: How should i do it then?

Comment: I linked a very good resource in my first comment.  Googling "How to make my game moddable unity" brings up good discussions.  [Streaming Assets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) is more similar to what you were attempting above.

Comment: @hijinxbassist `StreamingAssets` is compiled into the build as well on some platforms (e.g. WebgL, Android)  though ... `On many platforms, the streaming assets folder location is read-only; you can not modify or write new files there at runtime.` .. you could though place your default stuff there, on first run copy it to `Application.persistentDataPath` where users can now modify it (except on WebGL) and from that on you always use it from there